# Socket.io double connection with only one client

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am writing this server app (express and socket.io), just at the beginning.
I see double log, so I have double connection to server when starting a tab at localhost:8080.
What am I doing wrong? Is this a Socket.io bug?

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist", "index.html"));
});

// Socket setup
const io = socket(server);

io.on("connect", function (socket) {
  console.log("Made socket connection");
});
```

Comment: Looks OK. What does the client code look like?

Comment: FYI, `express.static()` already implements what your `app.get()` is doing, so that route is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that more js client files were calling socket().
Right method is to import socket.io library in ,  into your html file, so that this will be available to all js client file, implementing only one connection.